# jQuery - DatePicker showing up on top of text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a form with a TextField for entering a date. I have a DatePicker "set" on this field. However, it appears on top of the field. I do not want it to obscure the text field. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It shouldn't.  Can you write some HTML that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there's enough room below your input field for the whole date picker box to be rendered. By "room", I mean space in the enclosing window. The date picker tries to make sure that its display fits in the window, but it's pretty clumsy about it.

You might also want to look at the CSS for the date picker. In my opinion the default spacing for the calendar makes it ridiculously over-sized. You can tighten that up pretty easily; use Firebug to play around with it.

Comment: I had this same problem and it was caused by having the date appear at the very bottom of the window. When the page was scrolled up so the text field was higher on the page the datepicker box would render properly.

Comment: No, apparently it has enough space to fit in the page. (And @Pointy : Yeah, I've changed some styling, especially `font-size`)